How to lazily evaluate C# anonymous class property
I'd like to define an anonymous type, but only evaluate its properties some time later, after some processing.
private int _num = 1;
private int GetNum() => _num;
private void DoSomeWork() => _num = 100;

private void Foo()
{
    var obj = new { Number => GetNum(); };
    DoSomeWork();
    Serialize(obj); // should be { "Number": 100 }
}

This obviously won't work because you get the error:

CS0828: Cannot assign 'anonymous method' to anonymous type property.

Is there some way to work around this issue?
Edit: just to be clear, I'm perfectly aware I can rewrite it to this, I would just like not to:
DoSomeWork();
Serialize(new { Number = GetNum() });


Check the Lazy class. Why are you using an anonymous type when you want to customize its behavior so much though? Why not create eg a record with an extra read-only property?

Does the anonymous type have any other properties?

@PanagiotisKanavos No, it's just the one property.

I don't really want to use a record because I find that it would be cleaner to be able to just use an anonymous type in this specific case.

I think this job should be done by a custom converter or serializer. So this question is similar to: JSON custom serialization and deserialization of existing classes in C# asp.net core.

would be cleaner how so? Right now you're forced to use quirky custom code that could be just 1 more line in a 1 line record. Every time you want to make a change you'll have to search all methods that use something like that anonymous type. And unless that anonymous type has other properties, what you really need to serialize is the output of GetNum().

yeah, but why??

What do you mean I would have to search all methods that use that anonymous type? A serialize method should get all public properties of any type, period. My question was quite clear, it doesn’t matter how I want to use the anonymous type, it’s if I can use it.

One possibility is to use the Lazy<T> class to first define the lazily executed function calls and later use the .Value of this lazy object.
Enjoy this actually working example:
using System.Text.Json;

internal class Program
{
    private static int _num = 1;
    private static int GetNum() => _num;
    private static void DoSomeWork() => _num = 100;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var lazy = new Lazy<int>(GetNum);
        DoSomeWork();

        var obj = new
        {
            Number = lazy.Value
        };

        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj); // { "Number": 100 }
    }
}


I don't think this answer solves the question, I guess what the OP wants is to serialize a { Number = lazy } rather than the evaluated lazy.Value.

I know. But he should seriously check out this meta thread regarding the situation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 I would really love to know which actual problem he tries to solve.

@ˈvɔlə It’s exactly what I wrote, except DoWork actually does some work. It’s just a cosmetic choice I was curious about, because I find that it would look better (if actually possible).

Rather than storing result as object, why not storing lambda, which retreives it?
Change
var obj = new { Number = GetNum() };
DoSomeWork();
Serialize(obj);

to
var lazy = () => new { Number = GetNum() }; // lambda
DoSomeWork();
Serialize(lazy()); // invoke it or not

Fiddle.
Note: I make your initial code compilable and returning wrong result.
